# Familiar with the word "fadge"?

Tags: meaning

Anyone familiar with the word "fadge"? I have asked many people in the UK but none of them have ever heard of it. Most dictionaries do not list it. It is in the [OED](https://www.oed.com/search/dictionary/?scope=Entries&q=fadge), [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fadge), and [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/fadge), but the given meanings (to agree, to succeed, to deceive) do not match the usage well:

> "The Tories continue to treat women as a homogenous, largely
> middle-class bloc, hence their **fadging** about female directors and
> candidates." ([The
> Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/theguardian/2013/jan/25/simon-hoggart-week-michael-winner),
> 2013)
>
> "There is a line that connects Lyndon Johnson's lies over what
> happened    in the Gulf of Tonkin; the misrepresentations of the
> American government    during the Vietnam war; Richard Nixon's
> espionage operation against his    political opposition and the lies
> he told about it afterwards; the Reagan    administration's fudging
> and **fadging** about arms to Iran; and Clinton's    struggle to conceal
> the facts about Monica."    (The Guardian, 1998)

The closest sense that fits is "to deceive", but I'd like to pin down the meaning.

Comment: The last one in your OED link (variation of *fage - To cajole, flatter; to behave obsequiously; to speak beguilingly to*) looks the most relevant to me. I haven't come across the word myself though.

Comment: I only know it as an obsolete slang expression used in Georgette Heyer's Regency novels (and by her imitators, according to an Ngram search) - _it won't fadge_ meaning _it won't do/suit_.

Comment: [This CBS News article](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/the-history-of-fudge-did-a-mistake-create-a-sweet-treat/) says "to fadge" means "to mess up", claimed as the etymology of the word "fudge" for the confectionery, although while the OED agrees "fudge" is from "fadge", it doesn't give that meaning of "fadge". So I'd class it as unproven at best. It's possible it's dialect but not sure where - CBS mentions Baltimore and the first Guardian quote is Simon Hoggart from near Manchester, England (although his dad was from Leeds).

Comment: In his 1828 dictionary, Noah Webster says "This word is now vulgar, and improper in elegant writing."

Comment: Thank you. 

The meaning "to mess up" would fit in this example:
"Everything looked sort of fadged up that she had before her own mother died." (*By the Light of the Soul, Harper*, 1906)

The two *Guardian* examples above use the word in the form "to fadge about". Based on that usage if you had to define the word how would you define it?

Comment: Keir Elam's edition of *Twelfth Night* (Arden Shakespeare 3rd series) glosses the word as "work out" at 2.2.33, where Viola asks, regarding a romantic tangle, "How will this fadge?" The word appears to have a similar sense at *Love's Labour's Lost* 5.1.138: H. R. Woudhuysen glosses "if this [the proposed masque] *fadge not"* as meaning if it "does not succeed, fails to come off."

Comment: Really? How is Google wrong to suggest https://www.google.com/search?q=fadge+meaning&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB1057GB1057&oq=fadge&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i512l4j0i10i512j46i10i512j69i60.3372j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8